# PHP foreach Invalid argument supplied when decode json

Tags: php, json

I have to decode json data and insert it to database.

My code:

```
include 'db.php';
$jsonString = file_get_contents('../question.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$x=1;
foreach ($data as $key1 => $val1) {
```

And e error :
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /includes/php/transfer.php on line 6

foreach is my 6th line of code.

I did not get it.. where is a issue?

Comment: What does `$data` contain exactly?

Comment: you mean question.json?

Comment: Yes. Either the json is invalid and did not parse correctly, or the decoded json does not contain what you think it does

Comment: json data contains lots of data. array inside array etc...

Comment: check your json is valid or not here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: oo ye.. someone modyfy json data... Error: Parse error on line 64028:

Comment: Thanks... i was looking for a error in php code;p

Comment: You can check for a null value after json_decode to make sure it decoded properly. If it did not, then you can check for [json_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)/[json_last_error_msg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: when i fix json code in that line everything works. Thanks for a clue guys xD